# Продолжение работы только после создания файла

Tags: c#, файловая-система

Пишу программу в которой присутствует работа с файлами.
При запуске программы проверяется, существует ли нужный файл, если нет, то создать.
После создания, в него сразу же пишется нужные начальные данные.
И получилось так, что код работает быстрее, чем создаётся файл, т.е. команда идущая после создания файла срабатывает ещё то создания самого файла (он просто не успевает создаться).
Так как сделать так, чтобы запись в файл шла только после того, как файл будет создан и будет возможна работа с ним.

```
if (!File.Exists(NameFileWords))
{
    File.Create(NameFileWords).Close();

    FileWords.Load(NameFileWords); // Тут файл он ЕЩЁ не видит

    FileWordsRoot = FileWords.DocumentElement;

    XmlElement NewRoot = FileWords.CreateElement("Words");
    FileWordsRoot.AppendChild(NewRoot);
}
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> он просто не успевает создаться

*"Это - вряд ли." Товарищ Сухов "Белое солнце пустыни"*

---

Если Вы только что создали пустой файл, как Вы собираетесь загрузить из него XML документ?

```
//FileWords.Load(NameFileWords);
...
FileWords.Save(NameFileWords);
```